# Why is 10.0.0.1/28 not a valid subnet within a VPC of 10.0.0.0/24?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet

How to create Multiple Subnets within Range 10.0.0.0/24.
Tried creating 10.0.0.1/28 . It tells it should be within the CIDR Range. 
I am sure am making something wrong . Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `VPC` has : `10.0.0.0/24`. then you want to create some subnets are being this VPC.

If you want to create subnet with `/28` so:

`10.0.0.0/28
10.0.0.16/28
10.0.0.32/28
10.0.0.48/28
10.0.0.64/28
............
10.0.0.240/28`

If you want to create subnet with `/26`:

`10.0.0.0/26
10.0.0.64/26
10.0.0.128/26
10.0.0.192/26`

Answer (score 3):

The message is misleading. It is not like `10.0.0.1/28` is not within the CIDR range of `10.0.0.0/24`, it simply is an incorrect network ID (the message could be slightly more helpful I guess).

You can only specify network ID, not a network address. In your case `10.0.0.1/28` is the first network address from range `10.0.0.0` - `10.0.0.15` where `10.0.0.0/28` is the network ID that you need to use instead. The next network ID for `/28` prefix length is `10.0.0.16` as it was mentioned in the other answer.

This is given by subnetting rules. Long story short, if you need to know network IDs then just subtract the prefix, in this case `28` from `32` (32 bits of IPv4 address) which gives you 4 usable bits for hosts which translates to `2^4 = 16` block size. Therefore you can start with `10.0.0.0` and continue by adding 16 to the last number `0, 16, 32, 48, ...` and the same goes for the other prefixes as well (or at least if you consider any prefix longer or equal to 24, it kind of works for shorter prefixes as well but you need to be careful which octet of IP address you are modifying).

It is also worth mentioning that the `10.0.0.1/28` is not even a usable IP address **on AWS** because AWS reserves first 4 and the last one IP address of each subnet (first 4, including network ID, are used for stuff such as DHCP server in your subnet which you don't directly see and the last one is broadcast address which, in general, cannot be assigned to any host, moreover AWS doesn't even support broadcasts).

So technically, when you use `10.0.0.0/28` subnet, you will end up with 11 available IP addresses ranging from `10.0.0.4` to `10.0.0.14`.